# reading serial port but showing other types of character

Tags: java, serial-port

I am reading a serial port in which there are some characters like skljdf85789^&*^eeb etc..
In hyper terminal, I can see the port with normal characters.
Now, when I am reading it by using java, eclipse,
In console I should see smt like skljdf85789^&*^eeb etc.. instead, I see a sequence of frequent rectangulars. 
I think it is a porblem of incompatible types. I tried these:

```
 public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent arg0) {
        int data;

        switch (arg0.getEventType()) {
        case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:

            try {

                int len = 0;
                int bet=0;
                while ((data = in.read()) > -1) {
                    if (data == ' '||data == '  ' ){
                        break;
                    }
                    buffer[len++] = (byte) data;

                }// it writes to a buffer from the port
                                    String meterbuf = new String(buffer, 0, len);//buffer is a byte array, it casted  to String here.
                                    System.out.println("string from m485: " + meterbuf);
                                    for(int k=0;k<meterbuf.length();k++)
                {
                    char c=meterbuf.charAt(k);
                    System.out.print(Character.valueOf(c)+" ");
                                    }// I tried to get chars one by one, it did not work, too.
```

Do you have any suggestions?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was baudrates. I forgat to set the baudrates.
I am using c, "iar embedded systems" to write to the port and I am using Java, "eclipse" to read from the port. In both of the programs, the baudrates should be equal. if they are different, the characters would be silly:)